# Why am I getting an error in Hitting API using JSON

Tags: java, android

While I am hitting API using JSON I am getting the following error I don't know where is my error can anybody help in resolving it as I don't have much knowledge of Json Parsing

```
public void onPaymentSuccess(String s, PaymentData data) {
            String paymentId = data.getPaymentId();
            String signature = data.getSignature();
            String orderId = data.getOrderId();

            callvolly(paymentId,signature,orderId );


        }

        private void callvolly(final String paymentId,final String signature,final String orderId) {
            String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("posting...");
            pDialog.show();

            RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url = "http://staging.s.com//payment/validate" ;
            StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //This code is executed if the server responds, whether or not the response contains data.
                    //The String 'response' contains the server's response.
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //This code is executed if there is an error.
                }
            }) {
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    MyData.put("paymentId", paymentId);
                    MyData.put("signature", signature);
                    MyData.put("orderId", orderId);
                    return MyData;
                }
            };


            MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
        }
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request#getParams() or
>   Request#getPostParams() returned a map containing a null key or value:
>   (signature, null). All keys and values must be non-null.
>           at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:478)
>           at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:466)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:275)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:249)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:94)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:123)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)

Comment: You must be sending null values as values in map and passing it in the Payload. Also  there is error in the url

Comment: Check if values inside of the `getParams()` method aren't null.

Comment: It seems to me that your `paymentId`, `signature` and `orderId` are both instance fields and variables inside of `onPaymentSuccess` method. I think you've meant to set values to the instance fields in that method. If they weren't instance fields you won't be able to refer them inside of `getParams`

Comment: Have I done the parsing right ?

Comment: What parsing? The code above only executes a network request. Parsing should happen in `onResponse()`